# Can I start a state machine from a specific point?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I'm using a state machine to control the steps of a wizard in an ASP MVC solution.  Each state represents a page and creates a bookmark when it is reached.

When using the wizard the first transition works fine but subsequent transitions do not because a new controller is created per action and therefore a new workflow application too, losing my bookmarks.  I'd prefer not to persist my workflow - I'd rather simply pass in what page/state I'm currently on and start from there.  Is this possible?

Comment: I've just seen this post from May/June 2011 which suggests this isn't possible:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wfprerelease/thread/697f2b30-331c-44cc-9146-6f9603f84384/

WF 3.5 did have a SetState method but it no longer exists in 4.0+. It looks like I will need to create a new activity to direct the state machine to the "start" state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it always starts at the top. If you want/need to force it into a specific state you will need to model that into your state machine workflow.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected that might be the case :(

Comment: Hi Maurice, not even in 4.5 is that possible? I would like to try it too, to have only one live instance and set the "current" state and then run it...

Comment: No, AFAIK they didn't add the capability. Maybe add it to the [UserVoice](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/category/35687-windows-workflow-foundation) list?

Comment: I also want this behaviour, does anyone know whether we can dynamically add these additional transitions at runtime perhaps? I'd rather not muddy up my visual state model.

Comment: Is this the case with persistence?